# Is it possible to destructure a nested object without knowing the key of the parent?

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring

I was wondering if it is possible to destructure a nested object without knowing the key of the parent object?

The reason to do this is that mongoose validation errors returns an object in the `errors` key and each entry of this object is another object where the key is the name of the field that has an error.

```
const data = {
  name: {
    path: 'name',
    name: 'The error message'
  },
  email: {
    path: 'email',
    name: 'Another error message'
  }
}
```

So the result can be something like

```
{
  name: 'The error message',
  email: 'Another error message'
}
```

Is it possible that the unique way to do this is using `for in` loop and perform the destructuring assignment inside of it?

```
let message = {}
for (var k in data) {
  var { path, name } = data[k]
  message[path] = name
}
```

Comment: Can you show the expected result?

Comment: What would you destructure it into?

Comment: You can't destructure through a loop, though you *can* retrieve the value without destructuring. What exactly varies in the code you posted, and what's the desired output?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have updated the code.

Comment: Change to `message[path] = name` and it works

Comment: @CertainPerformance, then this is the unique way to do it, right? So, probably it is better to avoid destructuring and do `message[data[k][path] = data[k][name]`?

Comment: That looks kinda confusing, I prefer your current method with destructuring (just change to bracket notation)

Answer (score 1):

You could take the values and map new objects. Then assign all objects to a single object.

```js
const
    data = { name: { path: 'name', name: 'The error message' }, email: { path: 'email', name: 'Another error message' } }
    result = Object.assign({}, ...Object
        .values(data)
        .map(({ path, name }) => ({ [path]: name }))
    );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: no enough description for coding process

Comment: I have updated the description with the output I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.values` like so:

```js
const data = { name: { path: 'name', name: 'The error message' } };

const { path, name } = Object.values(data)[0];

console.log(path);
console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {
  name: {
    path: 'name',
    name: 'The error message'
  }
}

const {path, name} = Object.values(data)[0];

console.log(path, name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do inside `for in` by taking the key and accessing the value and destructure it

```js
const data = {
  name: {
    path: 'name',
    name: 'The error message'
  }
}

for(let key in data){
  let { path, name } = data[key]
  console.log('name --->',name)
  console.log('path --->',path)
}
```